level of details in SAP Lumira
I want to add new column i.e., sales by state, to this data:
State city sales
ABC    C1   1000
ABC    C2   1200
ABC    C3    500
XYZ    A1   2000
XYZ    A2   2200
XYZ    A3    100

it should look like:
State city sales   Sales by State
ABC    C1   1000      2700
ABC    C2   1200      2700
ABC    C3    500      2700
XYZ    A1   2000      4300
XYZ    A2   2200      4300
XYZ    A3    100      4300

How to calculate or create sales by state in SAP LUMIRA? Any formula or function to calculate sales by states?
Please help
Thanks.
